# Reorder an array based on values

Tags: arrays

I need to reorder an array so that all slugs get loaded before parents, but only if a parent has a value that matches a slug value exactly.

For example, take this array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [parent] => information_desk_3 
        [slug] => about_dream_portal_1 
    )
    [1] => Array ( 
        [parent] => forum
        [slug] => information_desk_3 
    )
    [2] => Array ( 
        [parent] => about_dream_portal_1 
        [slug] => testing_2
    )
    [3] => Array ( 
        [parent] => testing_2 
        [slug] => information_desk_4 
    )
)
```

I need it so that it gets ordered as follows:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [parent] => forum
        [slug] => information_desk_3 
    )
    [1] => Array ( 
        [parent] => information_desk_3 
        [slug] => about_dream_portal_1 
    )
    [2] => Array ( 
        [parent] => about_dream_portal_1 
        [slug] => testing_2
    )
    [3] => Array ( 
        [parent] => testing_2 
        [slug] => information_desk_4 
    )
)
```

But the catch is, it needs to search through all slugs and reorder them so that the slugs come first in the array, before the parents that match the value of that slug.  Please someone help me, I've been at it for hours now to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you really have is a graph, and you want a partial ordering of nodes. That means you can solve the problem using standard graph algorithms.

If you build a tree of items where each parent knows about all its children then you can do a breadth-first traversal of the tree to build your partially ordered output.

In your example it's a very simple graph:

```
forum -> information_desk_3 -> about_dream_portal_1 -> testing_2 -> information_desk_4
```

If you start at `forum` and walk down the tree adding nodes to the output list as you go then you'll wind up with the correct order.

If you have multiple disjoint trees then it gets a little trickier, but still shouldn't be too hard. You just need to figure out which nodes are root nodes and then walk each tree in turn.

Comment: The slugs and/or parents are not always the same.  What I need to know is if any of them match.  i.e. do any slugs match any parents, if so, order the array so that the slug is first.  But it needs to be a RECURSIVE search so that it orders the array in a trickling down effect, loading the slug with the parents first.

Comment: Sure, and building a graph will do that for you. Go through the original list, and for each element see if it's parent matches a node that's already in the tree. If it does, add this element as a child. If it doesn't. make it the root of a new tree and check your existing roots to see if any of them should be children of this new root. Once you've done that you have a set of trees that will give you the correct partial order.